# command line - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, command-line, sys

I got a very basic code:

```
import sys

file = sys.argv[0]
arg = int(sys.argv[1:])

def multiplier(x):

    if arg < 1:
        print('Put an argument in')
    else:
        totals = 1
        for i in range(1,x+1):
            totals *= i
        return totals



print(multiplier(arg))
```

And I'm trying to run this from the command line and I keep getting this error:

```
  File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
arg = int(sys.argv[1:])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a 
number, not 'list'
```

I understand the error, but I'm new to the command line so I'm a bit confused in the command line context.

If all went well, I'd expect something like this (Input/output):

```
>>> Python program.py 10
   3628800
```

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Doing `sys.argv[1:]` vs `sys.argv[1]` yields two different results. One will return the sliced list as a list with the remainder given to you. The other one will give you the object you specifically asked for. [here's more details on slicing and lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colon in square brackets denotes a slice of the preceding list object. In this case, you want just the second item (with index 1), rather than a slice of the list `sys.argv` start from index 1:

```
arg = int(sys.argv[1])
```